# Unable to upload a document to sharepoint using a winform

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, .net-4.0

I have created a c# winform which runs from my desktop, and I am hoping to get it to upload documents to our sharepoint server.

Currently I have the following code:

```
public void DocUploadTest()
{
    SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/");
    SP.Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(currentWeb);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\sourcefolder\doc1.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/destinationfolder/doc1.txt", fs, true);
    }
}
```

This code gives the following error message:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

So I attempted to get authorized by adding the following line:

```
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[user name goes here]", "[password goes here]", "oshirowanen.com");
```

Where [user name goes here] and [password goes here] are replaced with actual administrator level login credentials which has full access to sharepoint if logging into sharepoint formally from a web browser.  This login allows me to create folders, and upload files manually.

Now the code currently looks like this:

```
public void DocUploadTest()
{
    SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/");
    ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[user name goes here]", "[password goes here]", "oshirowanen.com");
    SP.Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(currentWeb);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\sourcefolder\doc1.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/destinationfolder/doc1.txt", fs, true);
    }
}
```

I now get the following error message for which I can't seem to find the solution for:

```
The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
```

Note 1:  The file doc1.txt does not already exist on https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/destinationfolder/doc1.txt

Note 2: Both the winform and the sourcefile are on the same local machine.

Note 3:  I have also attempted to use a different user/pass which has less permissions, which also gives the 401 error message above, instead of the 409 error message when a administrator login is used.

Comment: Some potentially useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369169/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-upload-document-409-conflict

Comment: Yes that fixed it, although it was not the accepted answer which helped, but the second non accepted answer which was useful.